# Android Gradle build fails from cached files

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am trying to build one of my android libraries and everytime I get the following:

```
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple build operations failed.
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0d92c5dbe3682b4fd3af323bb8f4fc81/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c9e81cc37c2c0c47883b955549c67149/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a60e256c2ccb687ca2c3dc1173bab875/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a31caec1a4d16ac05a41b0f552f96191/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9d3aed6b3e5d40e0d4373af6f3e198dc/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f9c01a9d9c0a59b69c3974ffcd3c9cee/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4d9724e0450bfaa483db25a04db0eb48/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a79286d8497b8365dabe35ac25780fe4/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2896cf3b957b3724a2dcfcee68be211f/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2896cf3b957b3724a2dcfcee68be211f/results.bin
```

with about 200 more lines of the same

I've tried `Invalidate Cache and Restart` from android studio and I've tried `rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches` but I continue getting the same error. I am able to build the exact same library on my other computers - I just can't get it to work on one machine in particular. Is there any other thing I might be missing that could cause this?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Okay so I finally managed to get it to work...

Had to run `rm -rf ~/.gradle` instead of just `rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches` which I guess forced it to reinstall all the gradle things and then the build worked

Comment: thanks for sharing this, got the same issue and deleting ~/.gradle works for me this solution valid in 02/2022

Comment: This was really helpful! I was always going for `~/.gradle/caches` folder. Then it would complain :/

Comment: man, gradle sucks... Thank you!

Comment: rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches doesn't help but rm -rf ~/.gradle does

Comment: I would first check the below answers. They are less invasive. And make sure that you save your ~/.gradle/gradle.properties if you have

Answer (score 34):

There's no need to delete the whole `~/.gradle` directory. Killing the Gradle daemon before clearing `~/.gradle/caches` worked for me.

You can kill the Gradle daemon using `./gradlew --stop`.

Comment: would you mind explaining how to kill the gradle daemon please?

Comment: how? ./gradlew --stop

Answer (score 3):

Better to use:

macOS, Linux, or WSL:

```
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

Windows:

```
gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

Comment: this didn't work for me

Comment: > Task 'cleanBuildCache' not found in root project

Comment: _„The Android Gradle plugin's build cache has been deprecated. It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.“_ — not really a solution.